# Converting Year, Month to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a DateTime object, but it seems to be giving me an error.

```
int month = "1"
int year = "2017"

DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.Day);
```

It doesn't seem to like DateTime.Day. It says an object reference is required for the non-static field.

How could I get today's day(16th) as a parameter? Also, I need the date to have hh:mm:sss... how could I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is this only Year and Month?

Comment: I only have the values for Year and Month, but I want the day to be today's day. Is there a way to get it through DateTime? I'm trying to insert this date into the database so I'm trying to get today's day and time.

Comment: Take datetime.now.day in another variable above and pass it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var day = DateTime.Now.Day;
```

for today.

You can add *hh:mm:sss* to the *date* object in the constructor too:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.Now.Day, 10, 11, 12);
```

- 10 => hours
- 11 => minutes
- 12 => seconds

Of course you can use DateTime.Now.Hour etc. for the current values.

---

An *ArgumentOutOfRangeException* is thrown if the values are not valid for a real date, e.g. 30.2.xxxx.

---

You can print the date object in different formats, read the [MS Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for all possibilities.

Comment: What does 10, 11, 12 mean? Thanks!

Comment: 10 => hours; 11 => minute; 12 => seconds. Of course you can use DateTime.Now.Hour etc. for the current values.

Comment: What happens when `month == 2` and `DateTime.Now.Day == 30`?

Comment: ArgumentOutOfRangeException as expected

Comment: @Eisfuchs - You should put that in the answer.

Comment: Updated my answer with all information from the comments.

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
 int month = 1;
 int year = 2017;

 DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

Take note, you declare integer without `quotation` marks:

```
int month = 1;
```

To convert it on 24 hour format with milliseconds as requested on comment:

```
string strResult = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}", date);
//Results: 02/17/2017 00:00:00.000
```

For 12 hour:

```
string strResult = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff}", date);
//Results: 02/17/2017 12:00:00.000
```

Comment: The format comes out to be 01/16/2017 12:00:00AM when I print it out. How could I make the format 2017/01/16 12:00:00:000 when I print out the datetime?

Comment: What happens when `month == 2` and `DateTime.Now.Day == 30`?

Comment: @vanillacoke9191 I updated my code based on your request.

Comment: I'm doing the 24 hour format - string strResult = string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/ddHH:mm:ss.fff}", date); - it is possible to convert it back to a datetime using this format? i tried, but to do a Convert.toDateTime(strResult), but it changes my format back to MM/dd/yyyy. i need to insert the date back into my database as a datetime.

Comment: @vanillacoke9191 - `DateTime` doesn't have a format - it's just a numeric value. Only strings have a format i.e. you convert the `DateTime` to a string using a specific format for the string.